# Swift: Is it possible that parent class class function returns a instance of subclass?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote the Swift code below.

```
class Animal {

    class func getAnimalByName(name:String) -> ?? {
        if(name == "Cat") {
            return Cat()
        } else {
            return Bird()
        }
    }

}

class Cat: Animal {
    func run() {
        println("run")
    }
}

class Bird: Animal {
    func fry() {
        println("fry")
    }
}
```

Then I want to write like below code without using "as Cat" casting

```
var cat = Animal.getAnimalByName(name: "Cat")
cat.run()
```

What should ?? in Animal class be ?

I tried AnyObject but when I built the code on iphone simulator, I got an error saying "methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Cat run]" though this compile successed.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? I know it's good to know if it's possible, but I can't think of any case where it would be more appropriate to do that instead of `let cat = Cat()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without a downcast, since it will have to go from *something* to the particular type `Cat` if you want to be able to call `cat.run()`. Return `Animal`, then you can use an optional downcast or a force downcast:

```
// optional
let cat = Animal.getAnimalByName("Cat")
if let cat = cat as? Cat {
    cat.run()
}

// forced
let cat2 = Animal.getAnimalByName("Cat")
(cat2 as! Cat).run()
```

That said, don't do the second one, only do the optional cast.

Answer (score 0):

You should downcast the object returned by `getAnimalByName` method,

```
class Animal {

    class func getAnimalByName(name:String) -> Animal {
        if(name == "Cat") {
            return Cat()
        } else {
            return Bird()
        }
    }

}

class Cat: Animal {
    func run() {
        println("run")
    }
}

class Bird: Animal {
    func fry() {
        println("fry")
    }
}



var cat = Animal.getAnimalByName("Cat") as Cat
cat.run()
```

Comment: Thank you your answer, but I don't want to use "as Cat" because it is pain to cast in spite of the function clearly returning a Cat object.

Comment: If you want to return a Cat object and a Bird object by calling getAnimalByName method, then the return type of the method MUST be a superclass of both Cat and Bird. When using that method Since the method return a super class object, you must downcast to call objects of the subclass